# Using DKIM from G Suite with Exim 4

Tags: ubuntu, exim, g-suite, dkim, ubuntu-16.04

I have a account in G Suite (Google Apps) and i made a DKIM, is possible use this DKIM to sign sent emails from my server through exim?

If possible, how i configure the exim?

Comment: Umm, so if not by SMTP, how *are* the mails sent?

Comment: @EEAA Yep, is sent by SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible use the DKIM generated by G Suite. The G Suite support said is possible use two DKIM for one domain.

So, i follow this article: [DKIM-signing outgoing mail with exim4](https://debian-administration.org/article/718/DKIM-signing_outgoing_mail_with_exim4)

This another article complete the previous one: [Can’t get Exim4 to DKIM sign outgoing mail?](https://blog.wturrell.co.uk/cant-get-exim4-to-dkim-sign-outgoing-mail/)